# Anime about space robot assassin on ship

Tags: story-identification, spaceship, robots, anime

It's around 15 or more years old.

A lone female on a ship alerted to intruder. There is a very dangerous robot that has a wide/asian/farmer hat. She fights it until the ship crashes on a planet.  I think maybe she rams the ship into the robots face into the planet and it gets up with only moderate head damage.

That's all that I can remember.

Comment: There's an [exchange dedicated to Anime](http://anime.stackexchange.com/). You might have more luck there.

Comment: This is most probably too little information. While there are quite obscure "identification-requests" over there, that get answered I doubt you'll have a good time with that little details...

Answer (score 3):

Sounds like Iria: Zeiram the Animation

Comment: What elements of that work make it fit the question?

Comment: http://th05.deviantart.net/fs5/PRE/i/2004/316/6/6/Iria_and_Zeiram_by_hellbeast.jpg shows the robot with the "asian hat".